# Ruby: drop elements in-place from the beginning of the Array and return the remaining array

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

Is there a method in Ruby that removes the first *n* items from an Array (or other `Enumerable`), changes the array variable, and returns the **remaining** elements of the array, as opposed to the elements that were removed?

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

```
a = ["r", "u", "b", "y"]
a.mystery_function!(2)
# => ["b", "y"]
puts a
# => ["b", "y"]
```

`a.drop` isn't what I want as that doesn't alter the value of `a`. `a.shift` isn't right either as in the above example it would return `["r", "u"]` instead of `["b", "y"]`.

Comment: Are you looking for `a.slice!(2..-1)`?

Comment: That doesn't work as it changes the value of `a` to `["r", "u"]`, not `["b", "y"]`.

Comment: You're right, I was too fast.

Comment: @GeorgeMillo Very Good post... I learned one use case of `Object#tap` for you.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. possible using [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) and [`Array#shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-shift).

```
a = ["r", "u", "b", "y"]
p a.tap{|i| i.shift(2)}
# >> ["b", "y"]
p a
# >> ["b", "y"]
```

If you want to monkey-patch the class Array.

```
class Array
  def mystery_function!(n)
     shift(n);self
  end
end
a = ["r", "u", "b", "y"]
p a.mystery_function!(2)
# >> ["b", "y"]
p a
# >> ["b", "y"]
```

Comment: `def mystery_function!(n) shift(n); self; end` looks a bit cleaner

Comment: @Stefan Yes.. I just thought about that.. and changed.. you and me are on the same track..

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["r", "u", "b", "y"]
a.replace(a.drop(2)) # => ["b", "y"]
a # => ["b", "y"]
```

Or, maybe you can define one:

```
class Array
  def drop! n; replace(drop(n)) end
end

a = ["r", "u", "b", "y"]
a.drop!(2) # => ["b", "y"]
a # => ["b", "y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to delete from the beginning of the array, it can be

```
a = ["r", "u", "b", "y"]
a.each_with_index{ |v,i| a.delete_at(0) if i < 2 }  #=> 2 is the no.of elements to be deleted from the beginning.    
=> ["b", "y"]
```

putting everything into its place ...

```
class Array
  def mystery_function!(x=nil)
    each_with_index{ |v,i| delete_at(0) if i < x }
  end
end

a = ["r", "u", "b", "y"]
a.mystery_function!(2)
puts a #=> ["b", "y"]
```

Having said the above, I feel using `shift` (as given in other answers) appear much more elegant.